# share a domain name beween php and mono

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, domain-name, mono

I've got a problem : I've got a dedicated server where I use three different domain names and php. Now, I've got a new website that I developped with asp.net. I installed mono, mod_mono and transfered my assembly inside `/var/www/mysite`

My problem comes up when I try to access my website. I tried IpAdress/mysite/ but it just gives the three and if I want "IpAddress/mysite/Controller1/Action1" it says 404.

As I said my server is apache and is used with php websites which has several domain names. 
As one of those domain name can be used for my own website, I tried to create a subdomain name let's say `mysite.maindomain.com`
Here is the content of the file `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/mysite.maindomain.com`

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.maindomain.com
    ServerAdmin web-admin@mysite
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite

    MonoServerPath sousdomaine.domaineprincipal.com "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server2"
    MonoSetEnv mysite.maindomain.com MONO_IOMAP=all


    MonoApplications mysite.maindomain.com "/:/var/www/mysite"
    <Location "/">
      Allow from all
      Order allow,deny
      MonoSetServerAlias mysite.maindomain.com
      SetHandler mono
      SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
    </Location>
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
    </IfModule>
  </VirtualHost>
```

When I call mysite.maindomain.com it says "137 ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED"

What configuration must I give to make mysite.maindomain.com or IpAdress/mysite/ work?

*Edit*

I tried to change the vhost configuration by putting a maindomain.com instead of the * 
Then I also ran :
`nslookup mysite.maindomain.com` and got

```
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53
** server can't find mysite.maindomain.com: NXDOMAIN
```

`dig ciiarena.guildwars2-rage.com`  and got :

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> mysite.maindomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 10196
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mysite.maindomain.com.  IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
maindomain.com.    9588    IN      SOA     a.dns.gandi.net. hostmaster.gandi.net.1342214675 10800 3600 604800 10800

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec 27 17:21:05 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 108
```

after a wget mysite.maindomain.com I get nothing on error.log. As a matter of fact the wget I tried on the server leads to a 302 redirection to another domain than maindomain.

Comment: On the Apache server can you do a: **dig  mysite.maindomain.com**      also a: **nslookup  mysite.maindomain.com**,  if they resolve,  try a :  **wget   http: //mysite.maindomain.com/**  (if no **wget**, try a **curl**, or failing that: **telnet mysite.maindomain.com  80**,   then enter: **GET /**), and have a look at the output  or  tail /var/log/(httpd|apache2)/error*.log

Comment: nslookup says "server can't find mysite.maindomain.com

Comment: Quick fix, add an entry to the local /etc/hosts file  e.g.  127.0.0.1  xxxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzzz

Comment: 127.0.0.1? and it will be ok from my browser?

Comment: Possibly, if the host name wasn't resolving locally you'd likely see a browser error along the lines of: **Oops! Google Chrome could not find mysite.maindomain.com**

Comment: but it does not work. It tried, restart my apache but nothing changed.
When I try mysite.maindomain.com on chrome I get "Unavailable webpage" and in the details it is written Erreur 137 (net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED)Unknown error

Comment: And do you get the same error from the command line on the linux box, if you do that implies there's a local DNS lookup error on the Apache server.

Comment: I put the error that I get on the linux box at the end of my question.

Comment: See quick fix above.

Comment: And I said I already tried it...

Comment: Check the ErrorLog as @arober11 suggested.

Comment: Ok so I will give you my error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing your questions and comments, I notice a number of things. But first, most importantly: **This is a DNS issue**.

- Check your DNS server and make sure that you have an A record setup for this particular subdomain.
- In the comments, when it was suggested to add 127.0.0.1 to your /etc/hosts file, that should have been done on the server, not on the client computer. Did you edit the /etc/hosts file on the server or on a workstation / client? If not the server, go back and fix it.
- When you are sure that your DNS issues are resolved, if you're still having issues, then make sure you include the subdomain's vhost configuration in Apache in the SAME file as your primary domain. But when you do, *make sure* to put the subdomain's vhost **above** the primary domain's vhost container.

Good luck.

Comment: this was effectively a DNS issue. Checking with my friends, the one who registered the subname misspelled it. I accept your answer and wish you an happy new year